# FATAL CiscoConfParse could not open xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.txt file

Tags: python, cisco, cisco-ios, ciscoconfparse

I have some cisco config files in the folder. I wrote the for loop to iterate thru each config files and find vlan1 ports as follows.  I check the permissions and security for the folder, files for all the config files and they're the same.  Ironically, CiscoConfParse can open, read, and produced results for some config files, but not others.  if I removed the config file that it cannot open, then it produced the result as expected.  When I put that config file back into the same folder, then it could not open and gave the [FATAL] filenotfound error.  I researched online and found some suggested solutions such as performing chkdsk /f /r and then sfc /scannow to scan and repair the corrupted files.  I did all that but the issue still persists.  I hope someone has solved this issue before and help.  Thank you

```
import os
import re
import csv
from ciscoconfparse import CiscoConfParse
def check_vlan1_ports():
    configs = (r'C:\Documents\Tutorials\Python\Scripts\NetworkAudit\Data')
    with open (r'c:\documents\result.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
        Header = ['Device', 'Rule', 'Exception', 'Status', 'Code', 'Severity', 'Reason']
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=Header)
        writer.writeheader()
    for config in os.listdir(configs):
        if config.endswith(".txt"):
            filename = os.path.split(config)

    #print(filename[1])
            parse = CiscoConfParse(config)
            vlan1 = parse.find_objects(r"^1\s+default.*")
            str_vlan1 = str(vlan1)
    #print(filename, vlan1)
            vlan1_ports = re.findall(r'(Gi\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})|(Fa\d{1,3}\/\d{1,3})', str_vlan1)
            if (vlan1_ports):
                with open (r'c:\documents\result.csv', 'a', newline='') as \
                            csv_file:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=Header)
                    writer.writerow({'Device':filename[1], 'Rule': 1, 'Exception': \
                                 'Check Vlan1 ports', \
                                 'Status': 'Failed', 'Code': '1', 'Severity': 'High', \
                                 'Reason': vlan1_ports})
            else:
                with open (r'c:\documents\result.csv', 'a', newline='') as csv_file:
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=Header)
                    writer.writerow({'Device':filename[1], 'Rule': 1, 'Exception': \
                                  Check Vlan1 ports', \
                                 'Status': 'Pass', 'Code': '1', 'Severity': 'High', \
                                 'Reason': 'No ports in vlan1'})
check_vlan1_ports()
```

Comment: Do you see that `"c:\documents\result.csv"` is not the same as `"c:\users\lang\documents\result.csv"`?  The best way to avoid issues like that is to store the file name in a variable.

Comment: thanks for catching it.  yes, I fixed it

Comment: And has that solved your problem?

Comment: no. that line just write the results to csv file.

Comment: ??? You're still writing "C:\Documents..." in two spots, and "C:\Users\lang\Documents..." in another spot.

Comment: Have you looked at those odd files to see if they look different from the working ones?

Comment: each config files are configured differently but they have the same format,  Its so weird why CiscoConfParse can open and read some txt files, but not the others.

Comment: I'm still struggling with using the ciscoconfparse module to open,  read, and parse the Cisco configuration text files.  some config text files can be read and process okay, but cannnot read other config files that have same format.  I'v been googling and read many posts to find out why, but no help yet.  Please help if you know why

Comment: This problem was also [reported as github issue #204](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/issues/204).  The problem could not be reproduced.  Note: before ciscoconfparse version 1.6.0, there was no config encoding parameter.  Explicit encoding was added in ciscoconfparse version 1.6.0

Answer (score 0):

This problem was also reported as [Github issue #204](https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse/issues/204). The problem could not be reproduced. Note: before ciscoconfparse version 1.6.0, there was no config encoding parameter. Explicit encoding was added in ciscoconfparse version 1.6.0